# Setting the Control Source of a textbox VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access, textbox, ms-access-2007

In my Access 2007 Form, I was previously successful in setting the controlSource of a textbox, directly in the properties window, using this code

```
=UCase(Left([txtLName],6) & "_" & Left([TxtFName],1))
```

However, in an attempt to hard-code this into the form, I'm trying to use VBA to set the controlSource property using this code:

```
Me.txtCodePersonal.ControlSource = "=UCase(Left([txtLName],6) & "_" & Left([TxtFName],1))"
```

In my debug, it address my problem to the `"_"` section of this line.

I don't know how the controlSource property work in VBA, so I don't know how to correct this.
Thank for all your help in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're attempting to assign a string value to the `.ControlSource` property.  However, that string includes quotes within it.  Similarly, in the Immediate window, this will throw an error:

```
Debug.Print "=UCase(Left([txtLName],6) & "_" & Left([TxtFName],1))"
```

Double up the quotes inside the string to avoid that problem.

```
Debug.Print "=UCase(Left([txtLName],6) & ""_"" & Left([TxtFName],1))"
=UCase(Left([txtLName],6) & "_" & Left([TxtFName],1))
```